# How do I send an attachment through REST response using Python Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask

I'm building a REST API, and it has to send a file in the response. I do not want to include the file content in the response body. Can we attach files to response ?

Comment: What do you mean by attaching files to response?  Even in SMTP the attachments are sent in the response body. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to send a file with `Content-Disposition` header set to 'attachment'. Which instructs the browser to download/save the file, instead of displaying its contents inline on the page.

If that's what you want, then you'll have to do something like this:

```
from flask import make_response

@app.route('/txt')
def attachment():
    resp = make_response('my text file')
    resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'
    resp.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=SmartFileName.txt'
    return resp
```

Comment: what about *reading* an attachment from a flask response? IE, if you have a programatic flask.wrappers.Response object; "getting the attachement" out of it?